# Package endfloat Error: Unknown environment `figure'

Tags: tables, rotating, endfloat

When I am using package `\usepackage[tablesonly]{endfloat}` along with `\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}` I get the error message

```
Package endfloat Error: Unknown environment `figure'
```

In my document I am using sideways figure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[paperheight=10in,paperwidth=6.5in,margin=2cm,headsep=.5cm,top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.13} \date{}


\usepackage[tablesonly]{endfloat}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter

\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Testing Rotate package}
\author{~}

\maketitle 


\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\bgroup
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
\centering 
\includegraphics[draft]{fig.png}
\makeatother 
\caption{{Test caption}}
\label{figure-50fffe3f4a3f3fba00f6aeaa236c36ec}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
\egroup
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Test & Test \\
\hline
Test & Test \\
Test & Test \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document
```

Comment: Delete the line `\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}}{}}\makeatother`.  Unless, or course, you WANT sdewaysfigures at the end, then remove [tablesonly].

Comment: or use `\makeatletter\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{table}}{}}\makeatother`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you used the **tablesonly** option to the endfloat package and you declared the sidewaysfigure as delayed float. To avoid this error change the code

```
\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}}{}
```

to below:

```
    \AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackagewith{endfloat}{figuresonly}
  {\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}}%true
  {\@ifpackagewith{endfloat}{tablesonly}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}}%true
  {\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaysfigure}{figure}\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{sidewaystable}{table}}{}}%false
  }%false
  }
```

The above code will check all the possible condition. Here we can use the commands `\@ifpackagewith` and `\@ifpackageloaded` for this.